# SQL - Select discint AND count from JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design

I have below query:

```
SELECT u.*
       (SELECT sum(trs.amount)
        FROM transactions trs
        WHERE u.id = trs.user AND trs.type = 'Recycle' AND
              trs.TIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
       ) as amt
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_by
          FROM xeon_users_rented
         ) AS xur JOIN
         users u
         ON xur.user_by = u.username
         LIMIT 50
```

Which selects some data from my database. The above query works fine. However, I would like to **also** select `count(*)` from `xeon_users_rented` where `user_by = u.username` This is what I have attempted:

```
 SELECT u.*
       (SELECT sum(trs.amount)
        FROM transactions trs
        WHERE u.id = trs.user AND trs.type = 'Recycle' AND
              trs.TIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
       ) as amt,
       (SELECT DISTINCT count(*)
          FROM xeon_users_rented
        WHERE xur.user_by = u.username
         ) AS ttl
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_by
          FROM xeon_users_rented
         ) AS xur JOIN
         users u
         ON xur.user_by = u.username
         LIMIT 50
```

However, that gives me the **total** number of rows in `xeon_users_rented` as `ttl` - not the total distinct rows where `username = user_by`

Comment: have you tried SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_by))

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want just by tinkering with your subquery a little.  That is, change the `select distinct` to a `group by`:

```
SELECT u.*, xur.cnt,
       (SELECT sum(trs.amount)
        FROM transactions trs
        WHERE u.id = trs.user AND trs.type = 'Recycle' AND
              trs.TIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
       ) as amt
FROM (SELECT user_by, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM xeon_users_rented
      GROUP BY user_by
     ) xur JOIN    
     users u
     ON xur.user_by = u.username
LIMIT 50;
```

Some notes:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` is not really necessary, because you can do the same logic using `GROUP BY`.  So, it is more important to understand `GROUP BY`.
- You are using `LIMIT` with no `ORDER BY`.  That means that you can get a different set of rows each time you run the query.  Bad practice.